# How to stop itunes from asking permission to allow computer to access info on my iPhone everytime i connect my phone?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, itunes

I connect my iPhone daily on a MacBook I don't want to access any info on my phone, so I don't want this question to pop up every time I connect my phone.

Comment: What is the exact text of the error? Have a screenshot?

Comment: Is my workstation, I don't want to sync files, I just want to connect it to charge. It has the wireless apple keyboard and wireless magic mouse, so I don't have to bring any cables to work, because it has one lightning cable to charge those to peripherals.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know of any way to disable it asking each time you connect it, but if you don't want to sync or transfer files, why connect it to the MacBook? If you're just doing it to charge, then perhaps connect it to an electrical outlet with the USB adapter it came with. While at my desk I connect my iPhone to a [charging USB hub](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00L2LK164).

Comment: Charging the phone using laptop is not a questionable idea. I do it all the time. Lack of power source, alternating between sockets, or simply not wanting to maintain multiple chargers are the reasons. Cable is easier to fit  in the sleeves and carry around than the charging brick.

Comment: I didn't say it was questionable. I do it occasionally also. But if there's no way to turn off the prompt to allow access to the iPhone, and he's connecting it to charge the phone, this is a possible workaround.

Comment: Your workaround is what I and possible OP are avoiding.

Comment: I need a solution, not avoiding that, and if that's is a mac problem it should be adressed.

Comment: Is my workstation, I don't want to sync files, I just want to connect it to charge. It has the wireless apple keyboard and wireless magic mouse, so I don't have to bring any cables to work, because it has one lightning cable to charge those to peripherals.